WinUI3: Applying a differing style to a ListView's SelectedItem(s)
I want to apply a custom style to the selected item on a ListView in WinUI3.
My first thought was to look for a property on ListView to see if there was a style to be applied to the selected item, but no luck there. Next up was to use a DataTemplateSelector, for which I made the below block of code:
internal class ListViewSelectedItemSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SelectedTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (container is not ListViewBase listView)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(ListViewSelectedItemSelector)} can only be used on {nameof(ListViewBase)}");
        }

        return listView.SelectedItem == item ? SelectedTemplate : NormalTemplate;
    }
}

But this proves impractical to work with since I need to declare 2 different data templates and maintain them together for just one tiny difference between them. This also becomes significantly more tedious when trying to change the selected item's style while also using another DataTemplateSelector.
Is there a cleaner and more simple way to apply a style to only the selected item (or its container) in a ListView, ideally through XAML alone?

Maybe you can use the ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle Property to define the focused appearance after checking DefaultListViewItemStyle.

So, I ended up with a sort of "workaround". It's by no means a particularly clean solution, but it does work and is semi-concise. I of course still invite better answers, but this it's what's worked for me so far.
I am not perfectly happy with this solution as it is relatively "unsafe", can cause UI glitching, and requires that the ViewModel behind each ListViewItem know whether or not it is selected, but in a pinch it gets the job done, and hopefully if nothing else can serve as a starting point for better answers in the future.
The long answer
First, I declared a style selector class that obliges the class implementing it to implement logic for deciding whether or not an item in a list is selected.

internal abstract class SelectedItemContainerStyleSelectorBase : StyleSelector
{
    public Style DefaultStyle { get; set; }
    public Style SelectedStyle { get; set; }
    protected abstract bool IsSelected(object item, DependencyObject container);

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container) => 
        IsSelected(item, container) ? SelectedStyle : DefaultStyle;
}

You may find yourself asking, why not do the following instead?
internal class SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style DefaultStyle { get; set; }
    public Style SelectedStyle { get; set; }
    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container) => 
        item is ListViewItem { IsSelected: true } ? SelectedStyle : DefaultStyle;
}

The answer there being that I found that ListViewItem.IsSelected is always false for all items, even when an item is selected. I don't know if that's a bug with ListViewItem or a quirk of my own code, but either way, it didn't work for me, so I had to implement an IsSelected property on my ViewModel (implementation details for that are project-specific and beyond the scope of this question) and implement the class like so:
internal class SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector : SelectedItemContainerStyleSelectorBase
{
    protected override bool IsSelected(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is IMyTypeViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return viewModel.IsSelected;
        }

        throw new Exception("Received a bad type");
    }
}

Then, in my XAML, I declared one such selector as a resource.
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="DefaultListViewItemStyle">
        <!-- normal styles go here -->
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="SelectedListViewItemStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">
        <!-- selected style overrides go here -->
    </Style>

    <styleSelectors:SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector x:Key="SelectedItemSelector"
                                                       DefaultStyle="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}"
                                                       SelectedStyle="{StaticResource SelectedListViewItemStyle}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemSelector}"
          SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"/>

The final problem to deal with was that the items container style was not updated when a new item was selected. This is where the cheat-y bit comes in: When the selection is changed, an event in the code-behind is triggered and re-sets the ItemContainerStyleSelector.
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object s, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView sender = s as ListView;
    sender!.ItemContainerStyleSelector = null;
    sender!.ItemContainerStyleSelector = Resources["SelectedItemSelector"] as StyleSelector;
}

Of course, this ignores the possible NullReferenceException in the event that s is not a ListView. It can also cause some slight flashing/glitching in the UI, which is why I am not perfectly happy with this solution. Note that ItemContainerStyleSelector is set to null first becaue if not, no refresh will be triggered.
The short answer (just the code)
// SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector.cs
internal class SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style DefaultStyle { get; set; }
    public Style SelectedStyle { get; set; }

    private bool IsSelected(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is IMyTypeViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return viewModel.IsSelected;
        }

        throw new Exception("Received a bad type");
    }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container) => 
        IsSelected(item, container) ? SelectedStyle : DefaultStyle;
}

<!-- MyUserControl.xaml -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="DefaultListViewItemStyle">
        <!-- normal styles go here -->
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="SelectedListViewItemStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}">
        <!-- selected style overrides go here -->
    </Style>

    <styleSelectors:SelectedItemContainerStyleSelector x:Key="SelectedItemSelector"
                                                       DefaultStyle="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}"
                                                       SelectedStyle="{StaticResource SelectedListViewItemStyle}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemSelector}"
          SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"/>

// MyUserControl.xaml.cs
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object s, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView sender = s as ListView;
    sender!.ItemContainerStyleSelector = null;
    sender!.ItemContainerStyleSelector = Resources["SelectedItemSelector"] as StyleSelector;
}


Try also bringing the DefaultListViewItemStyle and add VisualStates:
<Page.Resources>
    <Style
        BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListViewItemStyle}"
        TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
                        x:Name="Root"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        CheckBoxBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBorderBrush}"
                        CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                        CheckBoxCornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxCornerRadius}"
                        CheckBoxDisabledBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxDisabledBorderBrush}"
                        CheckBoxDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxDisabledBrush}"
                        CheckBoxPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPointerOverBorderBrush}"
                        CheckBoxPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPointerOverBrush}"
                        CheckBoxPressedBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPressedBorderBrush}"
                        CheckBoxPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxPressedBrush}"
                        CheckBoxSelectedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedBrush}"
                        CheckBoxSelectedDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedDisabledBrush}"
                        CheckBoxSelectedPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedPointerOverBrush}"
                        CheckBoxSelectedPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxSelectedPressedBrush}"
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                        CheckDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckDisabledBrush}"
                        CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                        CheckPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckPressedBrush}"
                        ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                        CornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCornerRadius}"
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                        FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                        FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                        FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                        FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"
                        FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}"
                        FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"
                        FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}"
                        PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                        PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                        PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                        PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                        SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                        SelectedDisabledBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedDisabled}"
                        SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                        SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                        SelectionIndicatorBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorBrush}"
                        SelectionIndicatorCornerRadius="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorCornerRadius}"
                        SelectionIndicatorDisabledBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorDisabledBrush}"
                        SelectionIndicatorPointerOverBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorPointerOverBrush}"
                        SelectionIndicatorPressedBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorPressedBrush}"
                        SelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <!--  Setters for the "Selected" state go here.  -->
                                        <Setter Target="Root.FontSize" Value="30" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" />

